# too many players on the court

Tags: rules, basketball, collegiate

During this past season, my coach subbed in a player from the bench and that player did a poor job of communicating who was to be subbed out. This resulted in our team having six players on the court (obviously not allowed). There was a span of about five seconds off the clock before the refs noticed. I had the ball and missed a long 3 after about two because I figured we might get to keep the points if we got them before the referee noticed our 6 players.

Its kind of a joke now between my coach and I, that with six players on the court, the best shot we got was a long three from me (not one of our top shooters). But in all seriousness what would the results have been if I had made the shot before the refs noticed?

(This was an NCAA game)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This will be incredibly dependent on the league you are in, so the best thing to do is ask the refs in your league.** However, my guess is that they'd follow similar guidelines as the NBA or NCAA, so I'll look at both of those below.

---

First and foremost, the refs should have called a technical on your team regardless of whether you made the shot.

For NCAA, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Too_many_men#Basketball):

> [C]ollegiate basketball (both men's and women's) limit teams to five players on the court at any one time. A team with more than five in play at once is assessed a technical foul for Too Many Players on the Court.

For [NCAA rules](http://www.naia.org/fls/27900/1NAIA/resources/sid/Rule%20Books/BASKETR.pdf), the technical would have resulted in "two free throws... be[ing] awarded to any member of the offended team" (page 103). I can't find anything specific on whether you'd keep the points in the NCAA, but fortunately the NBA is much clearer.

In the [NBA rules](http://mediacentral.nba.com/media/mediacentral/Official-NBA-Rule-Book.pdf), section VII.E addresses too many men on field specifically (emphasis mine):

> If the ball is put into play and remains in play with one team having six or more players on the court, a non-unsportsmanlike technical foul will be assessed on the team with too many players. *Immediately following the free throw awarded for the technical foul, the team with the correct number of players will instruct the Crew Chief to*:
>
> - **resume play from the point in time when the technical foul was assessed**, under the
>     same conditions as would have prevailed had there been no error with a throw-in,
>     jump ball or foul shot, as appropriate.
> - **nullify all play that occurred from the point in time when the ball was put into play
>     with one team having six or more players on the court and ending when the technical
>     foul was assessed**, and reset the game and shot clock to the point in time when the
>     ball was put into play, and if the ball was put into play by:
>
>   1. a throw-in, the ball shall be returned to the original throw-in spot with all privileges
>        remaining, if any, or
>   2. a missed free throw that remained in play, a jump ball shall be held at center
>        court between any two players in the game, or
>   3. a jump ball, the ball shall be returned to the original jump ball spot and a jump
>        ball held with the same two players.
>
> EXCEPTION: Acts of unsportsmanlike conduct and all flagrant fouls, and points scored
>   from any resulting free throws, shall not be nullified.
>
> (2) Other errors involving the wrong number of players at the start of play, four or less,
>   are not correctable. Following the technical foul, play shall resume from the point-of-interruption.

Under NBA rules, if you had made the shot, the offended team probably would have opted for option 2 and nullified all game play that occurred when your team had 6 players on the court, including your basket.

**Edit:**

The NCAA rulebook, Rule 10, Section 2 (Administrative Technical Fouls), Article 6:

> Art. 6. A team shall not have more than five players legally on the playing court
>   to participate after the ball becomes live.
>
> **PENALTY: (Art. 6) Penalized when the violation occurs after the ball
>   becomes live. Two free throws awarded to the offended team.
>   The ball shall be put back in play at the point of interruption.**

Since the Point of Interruption is when "a stoppage in play occurs," I would interpret this to mean that you would keep the points if you made the shot before the technical was called.

Comment: @John Well shoot. Guess I'll keep digging.

Comment: @John I edited to add the wording from the NCAA rulebook.

Comment: so basically I made the right choice :)

Comment: @John Yes. Shoot away in the future, too. Ya know... If you end up with 6 men on the court again.  :)